# SSL Error checking website with Python and locustio

Tags: python, ssl

I´m trying to check my website with a scritp of python, this is the script:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
 def on_start(self):
    self.client.verify = False
    self.login()

 def login(self):
   self.client.post("https://mywebsite/login", {"username":"ellen_key", "password":"education"}, verify=False)

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
task_set = UserBehavior
min_wait=5000
max_wait=9000
```

this method -> self.client.verify = False does not verify the SSL Certificate but I get this error:

```
POST /login: 'SSLError(SSLError(CertificateError("hostname")...
```

I have check my code agains facebook (just an user trying to login :S) and I get very well the request, but the problem is my SSL Certificate (I dont have one...)

Someone can help me?